# Cannot get the Todo-AngularJS-Sequelize Sample from Breeze working

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, breeze

I downloaded the Todo-AngularJS-Sequelize Sample for Breeze and tried running the node version of the sample but compiling and trying to run "npm start" getting the below error. Any help is appreciated.

Error: Unable to locate a registered object by the name: JsonResultsAdapter.webApi_default

I basically want to start with using breeze-sequelize. Is there any other sample code anywhere else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a new **breeze-sequelize** sample is sorely needed.  We (IdeaBlade) intend to add a `breeze-sequelize` backend to the suite of samples in the [Northwind Demo](https://github.com/Breeze/northwind-demo) repo, but haven't gotten to it yet.

Currently the best *end-to-end* sample is the [TempHire Angular](https://github.com/Breeze/temphire.angular/tree/master/Express) sample that uses an Angular 6 frontend with an Express backend running `breeze-sequelize`.

A more up-to-date *server* sample is in the [breeze.server.node](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.node) repo itself, under the [breeze-sequelize/test/BreezeExpressDemo/](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.node/tree/master/breeze-sequelize/test/BreezeExpressDemo) directory.  It uses the latest version of `breeze-sequelize`, but it's written to run the Breeze test suite and doesn't have a real frontend app to go with it.

Hopefully you can put those two together and get something that meets your needs.

---

EDIT 2021-03-19

The **breeze-sequelize** demo is available in the [Northwind Demo](https://github.com/Breeze/northwind-demo).  It uses the latest current Breeze and Sequelize libraries.

It's an end-to-end demo featuring a breeze-sequelize backend, with frontends using Angular, Aurelia, React, and Vue.